# using opencv in C++ error occured when return Mat object

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

// Used for library linking
#ifdef _DEBUG
#pragma comment( lib, "opencv_core249d.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "opencv_highgui249d.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "opencv_imgproc249d.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "opencv_video249d.lib" )
#else
#pragma comment( lib, "opencv_core249.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "opencv_highgui249.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "opencv_imgproc249.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "opencv_video249.lib" )
#endif

// Using namespace
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class Histogram
{
    ...
};

class HistogramOfRed : public Histogram
{
private:
    const int MaximumValueOfChannel = 256;

    Mat GetImage(Mat &image)
    {
        vector<Mat> RGBImage;
        split(image, RGBImage);

        return RGBImage[2].clone();
    }

public:
    HistogramOfRed(int bin, Mat image) : Histogram(MaximumValueOfChannel, bin, GetImage(image){};
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

    Mat image = imread( "test.jpg" );
    if ( image.empty() )
    {
        // Image is empty - image load error
        printf( "Image load error. Check directory.\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    imshow("original image", image);
    waitKey();

    HistogramOfRed histogramOfRed(256, image);

    return 0;
}
```

when I call `HistogramOfRed histogramOfRed(256, image)` error occurred.

below is callstack

```
.exe!std::allocator<cv::Mat>::deallocate(cv::Mat * _Ptr, unsigned int __formal)
.exe!std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<cv::Mat> >::deallocate(cv::Mat * _Ptr, unsigned int _Count)
.exe!std::vector<cv::Mat,std::allocator<cv::Mat> >::_Tidy()
.exe!std::vector<cv::Mat,std::allocator<cv::Mat> >::~vector<cv::Mat,std::allocator<cv::Mat> >()
.exe!HistogramOfRed::GetImage(cv::Mat image)
.exe!HistogramOfRed::HistogramOfRed(int bin, cv::Mat image)
.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv)
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message as well?

Comment: Is MaximumValueOfChannel used as a size or an index? If you have 256 histogram "channels", the channel indices would range from 0-255. I would expect the max channel to be 255.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is real error or you just copied it wrong here, but you're missing right parenthesis in HistogramOfRed(...) constructor

```
HistogramOfRed(int bin, Mat image) : Histogram(MaximumValueOfChannel, bin, GetImage(image) ) {};
```